# Calculate the rest length of a box2d distance joint

Tags: box2d

Given the length of a distance joint along with its frequency and the mass of the bodies involved, is it possible to determine the final rest length?
I'm only interested in the vertical axis if that makes the formula simpler.

E.g. Imagine the simple case of a dynamic body of mass=1 sitting vertically atop another similar body and attached via a distance joint with length=1 and frequency=1 and gravity=10.
What would the rest length be? I.e. What would the final distance be between those two bodies?

I'm currently just trial and error fudging the frequency values I need in my game but I really need a formula to compute this as every time I change the masses, I have to re-fudge everything.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the rest length eventually settle to the requested length? When I run sims using two bodies starting at either less or greater distance than the requested length they eventually settle to the requested length. What happens if you change the frequency to 0? It settles sooner to the requested length no?